# Spring Cloud Contracts and Spring Security issues

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, spring-cloud-contract

I am using Spring Cloud Contracts in projects to test microservices, everything is ok. But when I added Spring Security in the producer side, the **GET** return 401 status code instead of 200.

```
@Autowired
WebApplicationContext context;

@Before
public void setup() {
    RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(this.context);
}
```

My question is:

1. I have to avoid Security settings in the contract tests?
2. If I want to consider the security configuration, how to make it work.

Comment: Why would you want to get 200 if you enabled security? Have you passed the authentication details in the contract?

Comment: Add authentication detail using SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(testUser.getLogin(), testUser.getPassword()));

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak Yes, maybe need a simple way to mock OAuth2 authentication tokens in the contracts(and  a simple way to generate and check token).

Comment: Yeah that will be necessary to mock the receival of a token

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used a custom annotation on the base class, as documented here [test-method-withsecuritycontext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withsecuritycontext)

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@WithSecurityContext(factory = WithMockCustomUserSecurityContextFactory.class)
public @interface WithMockCustomUserDetails {
    String username() default "email@example.com";
    String role() default "DEFAULT_ROLE";
    String password() default "123456";
}
```

and then

```
@WithMockCustomUserDetails
class AccountBase {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options AFAIK.

A) Use authorization header

```
request {
    method 'POST'
    urlPath '/check'
    headers {
        contentType(applicationJsonUtf8())
        header(authorization(), "Bearer eyJhb.... ")
    }
}
```

B)
Add  @WithMockUser in my base test

```
import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@SpringBootTest 
@WithMockUser //this will ensure a mock user will be injected to all requests
public abstract class BaseTestCloudContract {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(context);
    }
}
```